# Box2d - compromise between rope and distance joint features

Tags: java, box2d

I am struggling with this issue since few weeks, I am making game using BOX2D physics engine (latest version) where I got crane, I needed rope, so at beginning I used distance joint, with anchor points set between hook of the crane, and its arm, it works quite okay.

I just draw line between those two anchor points, so it looks like a rope.

**Distance Joint:**

Pros:

- Little bit elastic look, looks and behaves more realistic.
- I can modify length of my rope on the runtime.

Cons:

- there is a minimal distance, so it often start to behave strange (trying to keep minimal distance) while rope is to long.

  - can lift only light objects

**Rope Joint:**

Pros:

- can lift any object, no matter how heavy it is
- there is no minimal distance, so it does not get crazy trying to keep minimal distance

Cons:

- is not flexible at all, so not really realistic.

Is there any way to combine them, achieving good result, where:

- can pick any load (no matter how heavy it is)
- can adjust elastics slightly to give it more realistic feel
- no minimal distance

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the rope joint connected to at the top? Maybe you could make the top body a little bit moveable eg. make it dynamic, and connect it to a static body with a soft joint like a  weld joint (and probably another rope joint to stop it moving too far).

Comment: Hello, I am responding to your answer "bit" late, but rope joint is attached to the dynamic body (for example, crane arm) it needs to be dynamic, because obviously arm is movable, attached to the main crane movable part (there are wheels etc) so I believe static body can not be used in this approach. Thank you for respond.